# New Global Picklist value not available to pick - not using record type

Tags: salesforce

-Added a new value to a global picklist value set
-Went back to the custom object, edited the field, but the new value is not there to pick!

Refreshed the page, etc.,  still not there.

Searching yields two main causes:

1. You are using Record Types, and you haven't updated the relevant Record Type to include the new picklist option.
2. The field in question is used in a Field Dependency, and the new value is not selected.
3. Clearing browser cache seemed to help one user in 2017

In my case these don't apply,  am not using Record Types, and no field dependencies on this custom object, and tried it on a different browser and got same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answering it myself ...

Here's what worked for me

I created another new value,
but this time I checked the box at the bottom *"Add the new picklist value to all Record Types that use this Global Value Set"*.
-saved this new value
-Refreshed the lightning page, and the new value showed up.
-Deleted the invisible value, and renamed the latest new value to what I wanted
-Again, refreshed the page, and now I've got my new value in the drop down.

Comment: When you try to rename the latest value, and api value, to what you want you may get an error and need to wait a minute or two for the Salesforce job to delete the old value